# How is recursion pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

How is the word '*recursion*' pronounced?

Oxford learner's dictionary lists it with /rɪˈkɜː(r)ʃn/  but Google serach shows /rəˈkərZHən/. 
never heard the later one anywhere else.

Comment: What do you mean with "Google search shows"? When I type the word in Google, it gives me /rɪˈkəːʃ(ə)n/

Comment: In my experience, the "sh" and "zh" sounds in the two pronunciations of the "-sion" in "recursion" are very similar--almost indistinguishable in normal relaxed speech.  The "zh" pronunciation is more common in the US.

Comment: I would personally pronounce it with /ʃ/ in BrE, but with /ʒ/ in AmE. Not sure if that’s just me, or if that’s generally true.

Comment: /z/ being the voiced version of /ʃ/, the former is easier to pronounce. But both are correct.                                                                                  Specialized context : https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recursion            2:48  https://youtu.be/WPSeyjX1-4s     https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recursion?q=recursion      http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9424.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Words ending in *-rsion* tend to be pronounced with /ʒ/ in American English for some reason, but they can also be pronounced with /ʃ/, and that seems to be the standard pronunciation in other parts of the world.

[Teflpedia](http://teflpedia.com/Pronunciation_exercises:_/%CA%92/_vs_/%CA%83/) says

> Several words are pronounced either with /ʒ/ or with /ʃ/. In most cases the difference is regional, with General American preferring /ʒ/ and Received Pronunciation preferring /ʃ/. [...]
>
> /ʃ/,<sup>BrE</sup> /ʒ/ or /ʃ/<sup>AmE</sup>
>
> - cashmere, coercion
> - ending in "rsion": aversion, conversion, dispersion, excursion, immersion, perversion, version

I hadn't known before that some American English speakers apparently use /ʒ/ in "cashmere" and "coercion".

Comment: Thanks, As Oxford Learners Dictionary showed with /ʃ/ for both BrE and AmE. So I was confused. Apparently, pronunciation with /ʃ/ sounds more common.