# Is the voicing voiceless consonants common in the US?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, north-american-english, consonants

I don't know if I should trust my non-native ears, but I've heard a couple of people (Katie from CollegeHumor is the first one come to mind) who say "thank you" with a voiced "th" instead of the proper voiceless one. Also quite a couple of people seem to have said "princible" instead of "principle" (like those guys from Corridor I think). I don't remember the exact videos where they say those words for demonstration, though.

So do Americans often voice their voiceless consonant if at all? Discounting intervocalic voicing which is more of a historical thing that happened centuries ago ("knives, clothes, Stephen"), this seems counter-intuitive to me, because it's more natural to devoice voiced consants, especially at utterance boundaries or if that consonant is next to a voiceless one (e.g., "slide" + a pause, in which /l/ is slightly devoiced because of /s/ and /d/ slightly so because of the following pause). Also discounting the North American tapped /t/.

Comment: Hello Vun, I am from the US and I have never said Thank you with a voiced th.  I also have never voiced the p in priniciple except  when someone is congested and can't do the non-voiced or from little kids who are learning.  I have never watched the shows you are talking about, but it would sound very weird to me.  But  remember that there are a great number of regional pronunciations in the US, so each can have different pronunciations.

Comment: The only word that comes to mind is _congratulate_, which some Americans now pronounce voiced. American schoolchildren might think the head of their school is a _princibal_, but they grow out of it.

Comment: Also the loan word _kindergarten_, which is almost always pronounced and frequently misspelled "-garden."

Comment: @shoover In AmE most intervocalic 't's are not aspirated (like in BrE) but are instead lenited to a flap (so 'writer' and 'rider' sound identical). But this certainly could be an instance of the OP.

Comment: Crap, forgot about the most American thing, that tapped t. Question edited.

Comment: Don't worry!  Eventually those voiceless consonants will gain political strength and find their voice!

Comment: Man, you're a riot. But seriously though, I'm discounting what that has been well known and obvious enough that they are discountable. Should've phrased that differently.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't that common to voice voiceless consonants. It does happen sometimes, though (the biggest example of course is intervocalic /t/ in certain contexts).

The two examples that you give are quite specific.

- Voicing the initial *th* in *thank* is known to be a feature of some people's speech (See [Voiced “th” in “thank you”?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15447/voiced-th-in-thank-you) on Linguistics SE and [Pronunciation of "thank" using ð (voiced th) instead of θ (unvoiced th)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236848/pronunciation-of-thank-using-%C3%B0-voiced-th-instead-of-%CE%B8-unvoiced-th) on ELU). The distinction between voiceless and voiced *th* does not have a large "functional load" and it isn't indicated in the spelling, either.
- I hadn't heard before about voicing the *p* in *principle.* It seems possible that this is partly an analogical change based on the large number of words ending in *-able/-ible*—although those are mostly adjectives, while *principle* is a noun. Based on Google results for the spelling "multible", the word *multiple* may be another word where some people voice /p/ to /b/ when it comes after an unstressed vowel and before word-final /əl/. I haven't heard of any analogous change of voicing /kəl/ to /gəl/ in words like *miracle, article, vehicle, oracle.*

In some words, sibilant sounds may be unexpectedly voiced.

- KarlG mentions the use of voiced /dʒ/ in *congratulations.* Some speakers use voiced /dʒ/ word-finally after an unstressed vowel in certain words where /tʃ/ would be expected from the spelling, such as *ostrich, sandwich.* I don't know if this /dʒ/ is actually phonetically voiced, or just phonemically voiced. Actually, the variation between /tʃ/ and /dʒ/ after unstressed vowels seems to date back to Middle English, so it didn't originate as a specifically American English thing (it's discussed in §4.2.1.5 of "Change in Obstruent Laryngeal Specifications in
  English: Historical and Theoretical Phonology", by Magdalena Jeannette Spaargaren, 2009).
- Voiced /ʒ/ is used where /ʃ/ would be expected in a number of words, such as *[equation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229654/are-there-many-tion-words-that-sound-like-vision),* [words ending in *-rsion*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449017/how-is-recursion-pronounced) (*version, dispersion, immersion*), and *fission.* The pronunciations with /ʒ/ have varying frequencies for each word depending on the dialect. Using /ʒ/ in *-rsion* words seems to be a specifically American English thing, while using /ʒ/ in *equation* is usual in all major varieties of English as far as I know.
- The distinction between /s/ and /z/ is relatively unstable in certain contexts/words (interchange between these is probably facilitated by the use of the letter S to represent both sounds). The final consonant of *versus* is often voiced (even by speakers who have not reanalyzed the word as an inflected form of a verb "to verse").

Comment: /ʒ/ in _fission_? That’s definitely a new one to me. Sounds like a Dutchman saying _vision_!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It's probably influenced by the /ʒ/ in *fusion.*

Comment: Still sounds very odd to me, unlike _princible_ and _multible_, which sound perfectly unremarkable to me. I could easily imagine myself saying those in normal speech (though probably not _discible_, presumably due to the different stress), but I think I’d actually be confused if I heard someone say _fizzion_, and wonder whether I’d understood them right. (There’s also cases like _possess_, parallel to _equation_ but with /z/ for /s/ instead of /ʒ/ for /ʃ/.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I didn't go into *possess* and similar words (*dessert, dissolve*) because the voicing there seems to have arisen before American English existed. But maybe I was being inconsistent, because the use of /dʒ/ in words like *ostrich* seems to be of similar antiquity.